# Microsoft Cognitive services - Speech customization testing processing seems freezed

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I upload sucessfully data to speech customization (wav audio+ txt transcription) for just one audio in a zip file according to Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-test-data. When i click to add a test i choose data and it's taking an eternity to process results and never stops processing. My audio is in pt-BR model. Any idea?

I cannot interrupt or deleting tests while it's processing

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an issue in the service, so it doesn't set the status of a test to failed, after we experienced an internal error. A fix for that will be deployed this or next week. After that you should see the test going to a failed state and you can delete it.

Afterwards you should be able to create an accuracy test with the same data and models and it should succeed.