# Azure Cognitive Services custom Speech-to-Text test seems frozen, how to stop?

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

A custom Azure Speech-to-Text test seems to be frozen, cannot be stopped/deleted.

I started a trial with Azure Cognitive Services, custom speech-to-tekst according https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-test-data. I succesfully uploaded some .wav files and a UTF-8 BOM encoded text file with one word/utterance per line. Next I created a test project and selected v4.2 unified and V3.0 universal (LM Adapt) as models and started the processing. The test type is inspection and it's status is processing, but that is now for 5 whole days.

I cannot interrupt or delete the test (error message: Delete test failed. Delete 'xxx test1' failed. Error message: The accuracy test did not complete yet.

I seems to be the same issue as this one:  [Microsoft Cognitive services - Speech customization testing processing seems freezed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532583/microsoft-cognitive-services-speech-customization-testing-processing-seems-fre/58077036#58077036)

Any suggestions on 1) how to stop/delete the test, 2) to get the test finished correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A new release of the Azure Cognitive services speech portal resolved both my issues.